# How to override powershell global module functions?

Tags: powershell

I have a powershell module file C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\MathModule\MathModule.psm1

I have added this so that I can access the functions in the module easily from anywhere. Lets say this contains a function called Add-Numbers.

I have another project where I have MathModule.psm1 with another implementation of Add-Numbers function. From test.ps1 in the same directory I write

```
Import-Module ".\MathModule.psm1"
Add-Numbers 1 2 3
```

I was expecting this to use the Add-Numbers definition from the locally imported MathModule.psm1. However, it continues to use the definition from C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\MathModule\MathModule.psm1

How can I override Add-Numbers from local MathModule.psm1 in test.ps1 instead of the one in Program Files?

Comment: Try this: `Import-Module ".\MathModule.psm1" -Force`

Answer (score 2):

If the MathModule module was previously loaded you'll need to add `-Force` to truly reload it (even from a different psm1 file).